Does Magic the Gathering need an independent arbiter for reliable detection of cheating?
In complete information games like chess, a player can always be certain about if and when an opponent cheats only given their own observations of the past and present state of the game because the decisions all players make (where to move a piece), and the board state are always fully public.
But Magic the Gathering has a lot of hidden state/information through zones like the library and hand, and mechanics like upside-down morph cards, which are only revealed later.
Do the game rules ensure that, at the very least when the game ends, each player knows for certain that the rules have been followed correctly - that no opponent cheated?
Which I could imagine happening through them manipulating hidden information in a way that is against the game's/cards' rules. Such as retrieving a card from their library that does not match the tutor's specifications (the tutors seem to require revealing the retrieved cards however, probably for this reason), or retroactively changing a decision to their advantage when it is revealed to the other player(s) (which might be prevented by making the player provably commit to it by writing their decision down)?
Do such situations actually exist which necessitate that an independent arbiter observes/tracks the game as well, so that evidence of the cheating does not get lost, and the matter of whether or not someone has cheated is adjudicated correctly?
If so, does the arbiter have to watch the entire game from both/all sides and note down every decision, or does the game ensure that they can always correctly reconstruct decisions once a player detects an incongruity, not using past observations?

It would be great if the people downvoting this question explained why they did so

If I had to guess, the question was asked a little paradoxically and conflates some concepts. No amount of rules will help against cheating because the very definition of cheating includes breaking the rules. And if the rules or certain cards knowingly left such a loophole open, it's not exactly cheating to use that to your advantage. That being said, the core question of "does Magic need an arbiter" is quite basic but valid, so I chose to answer it.

I intend it to be about the reliable detection of cheating. With hidden information, there exists the possibility of the game (accidentally) giving players choices that are unverifiable by opponents, so cheating may have occurred, but not provably

If you play a game of chess and your opponent illegally (but plausibly) moves a piece while you're not looking, how can you prove that cheating has occurred? Let's say they move a rook, you look away, and while you're looking away they move the rook another square in the same direction?

@Hackworth I'm assuming perfect observation

@2080 perfect observation is an unrealistic assumption

@Andrew Then let it be unrealistic - I'm interested in the theory of the game. I'm aware that the practice is much different. Assume a player recording everything with a camera from their point of view, seeing (only) what they see themselves, and opponents not being overtly obstrusive.

@2080 every competitive game could benefit from having a team of people watching every part of the game from every angle to ensure everything happens above board, the reason they don't isn't because they couldn't benefit from it (and benefit is different from need) but because of the logistical and realistic issues. There's not a single competitive game that wouldn't be in the abstract made better/more fair under such conditions, the conditions are just not possible.

FYI, the vast majority of cheating in chess involves getting outside assistance with making moves, rather than simply making an illegal move when nobody is looking. Such cheating used to require an accomplice, but in modern times usually involves plugging the current board state into a computer program and having the computer program suggest a strong move. For one of the most recent scandals, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlsen%E2%80%93Niemann_controversy

@Andrew: That’s missing the point of OP’s question: There’s a clear theoretical difference of whether or not there’s enough public information to verify that the rules are being followed.

"No amount of rules will help against cheating because the very definition of cheating includes breaking the rules."
That doesn't make sense. The question makes it quite clear how rules can help against cheating. For instance, requiring cards found with tutors to be revealed makes it harder to tutor an ineligible card.

Your logic (which you fail to make explicit) seems to be that if someone is willing to break one rule, then adding another rule is pointless, since they would be also willing to break that rule. But the point isn't that people will follow the additional rules out of honesty, but out of necessity. If your opponent is paying attention, no amount of willingness to not reveal a card is going to allow you to get away with not revealing it.

"And if the rules or certain cards knowingly left such a loophole open, it's not exactly cheating to use that to your advantage."
Of course it is. If there were a card that said "Deal X damage to target creature, where X is the number of creature cards in your hand", it absolutely would be cheating to lie about how many creature cards are in your hand.

I don't think this is quite the direction you were going for with the question, but I'll point out that the existence of card mechanics like Richard Turner suggest that even with a trained expert observing the shuffling of cards, you're still struggling to catch up.

@CortAmmon This could still be theoretically fairly mitigated without an arbiter by giving every player the opportunity to re-shuffle for anyone else after every instance of them shuffling, right?

@CortAmmon Hmm, I guess not only after shuffling but also choosing a random card(s) for them when a card effect requires this.

Yes, but only to verify deck legality
During play, all printed cards (un-sets excluded, along with online-only cards) are worded in such a way that their effects can be verified by other players. Hackworth's answer goes into more detail here. It's very difficult to prove a negative, but I've never seen a card which was not designed this way.
However, that only guarantees that cards are resolved correctly. The game does not allow players to inspect their opponents deck to ensure that the deck itself is legal. There are several kinds of illegal deck (some could be more easily hidden than others):

A deck with more than 4 copies of a vital card.

See this question for discussion of how this might be caught.


A deck with fewer than the required number of cards (e.g. a 59-card deck in a 60-card format)

The number of cards in hidden zones is not hidden, so theoretically their opponent could ask them to count the cards in their library at the start of the game, which would expose the cheating.


In constructed tournaments, players are required to use the same deck and sideboard for all games in the tournament, however, the lists are not revealed to their opponent. A player who swaps a few cards out (for example, someone who talks to their opponent's previous opponent to find out what kind of deck they're up against and then makes a few sideboard swaps before game 1) cannot be caught except by a judge.


Similarly running too few cards for the format isn't particularly noticeable, especially given that different ways of sleeving a deck will mean different per card thicknesses

@Caleth - While it's true that it wouldn't usually be caught, the number of cards remaining in the other player's library is public information. A player can ask their opponent "how many cards are left in your library" and their opponent must either count or allow them to count.

you'd have to count all zones, i.e. suspect they were short on cards

I am no expert player, but it seems to me that many of these issues could be solved by making the decks and sideboard lists public after the tournament is over. Is this not common practice?

@FedericoPoloni It is for at least important tournaments, but at that point it's way too late. How would you prove a few days later that your opponent played a sideboard card in game 1? Keeping exact score sheets like in Chess is enormously impractical in Magic.

Can't you pile shuffle your opponent's deck at the beginning of games to count it?

Some games, like Yugioh, aren't designed this way. Yugioh has a whole bunch of cases where the game depends on players being honest about private knowledge. This is at least in part because so many game elements were invented ad-hoc to make an interesting manga, instead of to make a practical card game.

Under the parameters of the question, why would this need an arbitrator after the game is over? Couldn't both players check each other's deck for validity after the game has been played?

@trlkly They could, but nothing in MTG's rules requires it, which is what the question is asking about.

@trlkly - Additionally, in a tournament setting, multiple games are played in a row with the same decks (with a few cards swapped from the sideboard). If deck inspection is allowed after each game, that would reveal previously hidden information before sideboarding to the next game. If deck inspection isn't allowed until after all games are complete, then it would be possible to run an illegal deck in game 1.

Aren't there cards that require your opponent to reveal cards from their hand if they are correctly named, too?

@Brondahl - No. The way those cards are written: you name a card, then your opponent reveals their entire hand, then they take some action (such as discarding or exiling) any cards which match the named card. I can think of one online only card which requires the opponent to only partially reveal their hand (only "nonland, noncreature" cards, I think), but that card has never been printed in paper because it would be unverifiable.

Within the rules, the game does not need an arbiter. Cheating is another matter.
The rules of the game, together with the card designs, make sure that cards whose abilities affect the game state or have to fulfill certain criteria will at some point be visible to all players, if only at the end of the game. Some casual (not tournament-legal) game variants that put more emphasis on the social aspect of Magic might have exceptions, such as the Un-sets or certain multiplayer variants, but these are not discussed in the Comprehensive Rules that describe typical tournament formats.
For example, when a tutor effect allows you to search your library for a creature card and put it in your hand, you will always be required to reveal that card before you do that.
For another example, if you play a card as a 2/2 morph creature and that creature survives until the end of the game, it has to be revealed as the game ends to make sure you were allowed to play it as a morph.

708.9. If a face-down permanent or a face-down component of a merged permanent moves from the battlefield to any other zone, its owner must reveal it to all players as they move it. If a face-down spell moves from the stack to any zone other than the battlefield, its owner must reveal it to all players as they move it. If a player leaves the game, all face-down permanents, face-down components of merged permanents, and face-down spells owned by that player must be revealed to all players. At the end of each game, all face-down permanents, face-down components of merged permanents, and face-down spells must be revealed to all players.

That being said, rules violations both intentional and not do happen, of course. For that reason, each official tournament is required to have a Head Judge, an WotC-accredited person with sufficient knowledge of the game rules and tournament organization. The Head Judge assists players and ensure the orderly conduct of the tournament, including checking allegations of cheating, as described in the Magic Tournament Rules (MTR). The MTR further define the types of information in a game of Magic and how players are required to keep track of them.
This Head Judge requirement, however, is not part of the Comprehensive Rules that govern an individual game of Magic. Any game of Magic can correctly finish without any outside supervision at all. If cheating occurs, then the rules are not to blame, because by definition, they have been broken by the cheater.

I will add that MTG judges don't exactly fill the "independent arbiter" role as the question describes it. Judges do not watch any single game continuously, so they generally have less information about the game state than either player has.

"The rules of the game, together with card designs, make sure that cards whose abilities affect the game state or have to fulfill certain criteria will at some point be visible to all players, if only at the end of the game." While I believe this is true for each individual card, I also believe there are some multi-card interactions (perhaps most famously Brainstorm + Sylvan Library) where this isn't true. I know how that specific interaction plays out in tournament settings, but I wouldn't know for every possible interaction.

@PhilipKendall What exactly is the issue with Brainstorm + SL? If it's about clearly marking which card was drawn how, then that's a failure to follow card instructions that can be immediately noticed by opponent. If the game asks about whether or not a card has been drawn this turn, then the implication is that it's a piece of info the game (and thus the players) keep track of.

It can't necessarily be noticed by the opponent because the player is (generally) at liberty to shuffle their hand at any point, and generally will do when resolving Brainstorm to avoid revealing whether the cards they put back are cards they drew this turn. But if you do that with a Sylvan Library trigger on the stack, the opponent can no longer verify that the cards put back with SL were in fact drawn this turn. It plays out differently in paper, where the interaction is very slighty nerfed, as opposed to MTGO where there is an independent arbiter.

@PhilipKendall Yes, "generally" they are at liberty to shuffle their hands, when it doesn't matter for the game state. If a card such as Sylvan Library needs to know which cards they've drawn this turn, then they're not at liberty.

Technically, it is possible to resolve a Brainstorm during your upkeep without knowing that you will need to handle a Sylvan Library trigger. For example, with Leyline of Anticipation, you could resolve the Brainstorm, then resolve a different draw spell, then cast Sylvan Library all during your upkeep. However, I believe the standard resolution for a situation like that is that when resolving the Sylvan Library trigger, you are only allowed to put back cards you kept separate to establish that you drew them that turn.

@murgatroid99 Arguably, if your deck allows for such a scenario, you are obliged to keep track of the cards drawn at all times since it might matter in a future game state., and thus, the game state. But if that's too far out and you're not obliged to account for non-deterministic future game states, then an arbiter could not help either because the information does not exist.

The point is that Sylvan Library doesn't actually create an obligation to track every card you drew that turn, it just restricts you to putting back cards that you drew that turn. It's perfectly consistent to not track those cards at all, and not put anything back.

@murgatroid99 How about we move this to chat? I'd like to ask you to clarify what you're saying here

@Hackworth An opponent might also find a way to gift and make the player play the second card, thus forcing everyone to keep track of this information at all times, (also so they can share it with the opponent when if they take control)?

@murgatroid99 At the lowest level of the "judge iceberg" there are a couple interactions that cannot be resolved without an independent arbiter.  It's just Sylvan Library/Brainstorm examples are by far the most common since both cards see tournament play.  A list of current examples might be an interesting separate question.

@PhilipKendall can you make this an answer so it can be upvoted, none of the answers explicitly mention this kind of case?

Magic the Gathering has Judges, I'm one of them. No we don't watch the whole of every game, that would mean one judge for every two players and is just not possible when you have hundreds or thousands in some events. At later games in the finals when there are only a handful of tables left, then yes judges will watch games more closely. Usually we get called in when a player sees something they think is questionable.
There is a lot more that a judge can tell about what happened in a game than a lot of players think just by looking at game state and asking questions. Most of the time you can count cards and turns to see if any extra cards were drawn, can count game state on lands, and so many other things to verify a legal game state. Though we can look at your examples:

Retrieving a card from their library that does not match the tutor's specifications (the tutors seem to require revealing the retrieved cards however, probably for this reason)

Correct. Every single tutor that has any kind of restrictions on it either puts the card found into play (where it will be public, and thus revealed) or requires the player reveal the card they found before putting it in their hand or on top of their library to prove that it matches the restrictions. The only tutors that don't require revealing the card are ones like Demonic Tutor where there is no restrictions, so every card will be legal to find.

retroactively changing a decision to their advantage when it is revealed to the other player(s) (which might be prevented by making the player provably commit to it by writing their decision down)?

Magic does tend to avoid simultaneous decisions as much as it can to avoid scenarios like this, but when they do, yes, usually players make these decisions in some concrete way, for example with wheel of misfortune players often write their number down or choose it with hidden dice that they will reveal so it's hard to change when revealing.
Will this prevent every case of cheating, no, in a game of imperfect information it's pretty much impossible to prevent everything, even if someone is always watching. The game and tournament rules are set up as they are to try and limit cheating as much as possible, from your opponent always cutting your deck after shuffles, to the examples discussed. Independent arbiters for each just aren't feasible, most of the time between the rules structures and judges, it's not perfect but it's the best we really can have.

I think you're answering the wrong question here. The question isn't "is it possible for an independent arbiter to determine if a player was cheating?", but "are there situations by which an independent arbiter would be required in order to determine if a player was cheating?" The OP wants to know if there's a way by which a player could cheat through actions taken purely in hidden zones or with hidden information while all visible actions or information were precisely in line with the Comp Rules, or if the Comp Rules as-is are structured in such a way that that would be impossible.

First of all, as mentioned, it's worth noting that one aspect of cheating (that is actually seen in chess tournaments) is whether there is any outside help, such as from an AI.
Ignoring that, then I believe the question is really whether or not someone can completely observe the game play to determine if there was any cheating.
In MtG, this is not initially the case, because there is information in the deck of cards that is hidden (such as number of cards, specific cards, etc..), but also allows for cheating by a clever card manipulator (such as not dealing from the top of the deck, etc.., improperly shuffling).
You could allow players to shuffle each other's decks to ensure they haven't "stacked" their deck in a specific way.  That solves one possibility of cheating.
You can also solve the issue of deck construction and still have the contents of the deck initially unknown to the opposing player by using a cryptographic hash - i.e., once the deck is shuffled you come up with a text list of all the cards in order, then you come up with a public cryptographic hash of that list which can be known at the start of the game (without revealing the cards themselves).  At the end of the game the players must reveal their private key for the cryptographic hash and then the card identity and order in the game can be confirmed.
Unfortunately the second technique conflicts with the first, unless you have an arbiter of some sort that can track the deck (and then you wouldn't need a hash).  Of course - this arbiter could be automated, something that scans the deck after it's been shuffled and then this would be able to handle ensuring deck ordering in play (as well as construction).
But there's another form of cheating that you can't really discover by simply looking at the game play afterwards, and that's peeking.  If the player is able to peek at their down cards (or yours) then that won't show up in the final game play.
There's certainly techniques you can use to minimize this type of cheating, but delve into magic (as in "tricks" instead of "the gathering") and you will be shocked with what is possible, including having rfid encoded cards that can be read by a palm reader/ring.
So, to answer your question in the end, MtG is not something where all forms of cheating can be determined by simply looking at the game play afterwards.
Though this is not fully true of chess anyways.
